# Не работает функция добавить запись в базу

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter

Помогите пллиз. Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/luba/PycharmProjects/SQL_database_Tkinter/main.py", line 45, in addData
    stdDatabase_BackEnd.addWorRec(WorID.get(), Firstname.get(), Surname.get(), Posada.get(), Age.get(), Gender.get(), Adress.get(), Mobile.get())
  File "/Users/luba/PycharmProjects/SQL_database_Tkinter/stdDatabase_BackEnd.py", line 18, in addWorRec
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO worker VALUES (NULL,  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",WorID, Firstname, Surname , Posada, Age, Gender, Adress, Mobile)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (9 given)
```

А вот сам код из файлов

```
import sqlite3



def workerData():
    con = sqlite3.connect("worker.db")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS worker(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, WorID text, Firstname text,  \
                    Surname text, Posada text, Age text, Gender text, Adress text, Mobile text)")

    con.commit()
    con.close()



def addWorRec(WorID, Firstname, Surname, Posada, Age, Gender, Adress, Mobile):
    con = sqlite3.connect("worker.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO worker VALUES (NULL,  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",WorID, Firstname, Surname , Posada, Age, Gender, Adress, Mobile)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

и еще -

```
def addData():
    if (len(WorID.get())!= 0):
        stdDatabase_BackEnd.addWorRec(WorID.get(), Firstname.get(), Surname.get(), Posada.get(), Age.get(), Gender.get(), Adress.get(), Mobile.get())
        workerlist.delete(0,END)
        workerlist.insert(END,(WorID.get(), Firstname.get(), Surname.get(), Posada.get(), Age.get(), Gender.get(), Adress.get(), Mobile.get()))


def displayData():
    workerlist.delete(0,END)
    for row in stdDatabase_BackEnd.viewData():
        workerlist.insert(END, row, str(""))
```

что у меня не так ?

Comment: поправьте оформление

Comment: Метод `execute` принимает два аргумента - сам запрос и кортеж с параметрами запроса (или как словарь). Вы передаете параметры запроса не в кортеже, а просто как параметры метода `execute`. См докуметацию: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить строку с запросом в базу данных на это:

```
cursor.execute(str(f"INSERT INTO worker VALUES (NULL, {WorID}, {Firstname}, {Surname}, {Posada}, {Age}, {Gender}, {Adress}, {Mobile})"))
```